# Invalid Depfile Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am working on a flutter web project and made no updates to the file but, it seems like there may be a new flutter update that have caused an Invalid Depfile error. I ran "Flutter clean" but, that did not work. It seems like many of the imports arent being

```
    Invalid depfile: /Users/hsi/Documents/buddieswebapp/.dart_tool/flutter_build/2d3c585b346bbabf643bbc9bd57ff66b/kernel_snapshot.d
    Invalid depfile: /Users/hsi/Documents/buddieswebapp/.dart_tool/flutter_build/2d3c585b346bbabf643bbc9bd57ff66b/kernel_snapshot.d
    lib/Account/AccountDetailsPage.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html' 
    import 'dart:html' as html;                                             
           ^                                                                
    lib//HomeScreens/HomePage.dart:19:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';                                                     
           ^                                                                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_web-1.0.9/lib/image_picker_web.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html' as html;                                             
           ^                                                                
    lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';                                                     
           ^                                                                
    Error: Could not resolve the package 'google_maps' in 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart'.
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';                                                     
           ^                                                                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_web-1.0.9/lib/src/web_image_picker.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html' as html;                                             
           ^                                                                
    lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart'
    import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart' hide Icon;                
           ^                                                                
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:4:8: Error: Not found: 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart'
    import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';                          
           ^                                                                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3-nullsafety.3/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
    export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;            
    ^                                                                       
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html' as html;                                             
           ^                                                                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html' as html;                                             
           ^                                                                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/utils.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';                                                     
           ^                                                                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/facebook_web_sdk-0.0.9/lib/src/fb.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
    import 'dart:js';                                                       
           ^                                                                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_web_image_picker-0.0.2/lib/src/web_image_picker.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html' as html;                                             
           ^                                                                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_browser_loader-0.0.6+1/lib/src/script.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';                                                     
           ^                                                                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_browser_loader-0.0.6+1/lib/src/script.dart:4:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
    import 'dart:js' as js;                                                 
           ^                                                                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_browser_loader-0.0.6+1/lib/src/style.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';                                                     

../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:223:31: Error: Type 'html.EventListener' not found.
      void removePopStateListener(html.EventListener fn);                   
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:287:3: Error: Type 'html.Location' not found.
      html.Location get _location => html.window.location;                  
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                         
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:288:3: Error: Type 'html.History' not found.
      html.History get _history => html.window.history;                     
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                          
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:291:28: Error: Type 'html.EventListener' not found.
      void addPopStateListener(html.EventListener fn) {                     
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:296:31: Error: Type 'html.EventListener' not found.
      void removePopStateListener(html.EventListener fn) {                  
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/utils.dart:7:7: Error: Type 'AnchorElement' not found.
    final AnchorElement _urlParsingNode = AnchorElement();                  
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                     
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/utils.dart:20:7: Error: Type 'Element' not found.
    final Element? _baseElement = document.querySelector('base');           
          ^^^^^^^                                                           
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_browser_loader-0.0.6+1/lib/src/script.dart:11:8: Error: Type 'ScriptElement' not found.
    Future<ScriptElement> loadScript(                                       
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                    
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_browser_loader-0.0.6+1/lib/src/style.dart:10:8: Error: Type 'StyleElement' not found.
    Future<StyleElement> loadInlineStyle(String style, {String id}) {       
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                     
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_browser_loader-0.0.6+1/lib/src/style.dart:28:8: Error: Type 'LinkElement' not found.
    Future<LinkElement> loadLink(                                           
           ^^^^^^^^^^^                                                      
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_browser_loader-0.0.6+1/lib/src/utils.dart:4:5: Error: Type 'Element' not found.
    Map<Element, Future> _mapper = {};                                      
        ^^^^^^^                                                             
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_browser_loader-0.0.6+1/lib/src/utils.dart:6:30: Error: Type 'Element' not found.
    Future<T> waitLoad<T extends Element>(T element) {                      
                                 ^^^^^^^                                    
    lib/Account/AccountDetailsPage.dart:32:10: Error: 'File' isn't a type.  
        html.File mediaFile =                                               
             ^^^^                                                           
    lib/Account/AccountDetailsPage.dart:33:18: Error: Method not found: 'File'.
            new html.File(mediaData.data, mediaData.fileName, {'type': mimeType});
                     ^^^^                                                   
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_web-1.0.9/lib/image_picker_web.dart:33:16: Error: 'FileUploadInputElement' isn't a type.
        final html.FileUploadInputElement input = html.FileUploadInputElement();
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                         
                      ^^^^                                                  
    lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart:108:22: Error: The method 'Marker' isn't defined for the class '_TrackingPage'.
     - '_TrackingPage' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart' ('lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Marker'.
          final marker = Marker(MarkerOptions()                             
                         ^^^^^^                                             
    lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart:108:29: Error: The method 'MarkerOptions' isn't defined for the class '_TrackingPage'.
     - '_TrackingPage' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart' ('lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MarkerOptions'.
          final marker = Marker(MarkerOptions()                             
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                               
    lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart:109:22: Error: The method 'LatLng' isn't defined for the class '_TrackingPage'.
     - '_TrackingPage' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart' ('lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'LatLng'.
            ..position = LatLng(order.venue.lat, order.venue.lng)           
                         ^^^^^^                                             
    lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart:113:26: Error: The method 'Marker' isn't defined for the class '_TrackingPage'.
     - '_TrackingPage' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart' ('lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Marker'.
          final userMarker = Marker(MarkerOptions()                         
                             ^^^^^^                                         
    lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart:113:33: Error: The method 'MarkerOptions' isn't defined for the class '_TrackingPage'.
     - '_TrackingPage' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart' ('lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MarkerOptions'.
          final userMarker = Marker(MarkerOptions()                         
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           
    lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart:114:22: Error: The method 'LatLng' isn't defined for the class '_TrackingPage'.
     - '_TrackingPage' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart' ('lib/Orders/Tracking/TrackingPage.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'LatLng'.
            ..position = LatLng(userLat, userLong)                          
                         ^^^^^^                                             
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:40:28: Error: Method not found: 'MapOptions'.
        final mapOptions = new MapOptions()                                 
                               ^^^^^^^^^^                                   
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:51:11: Error: Method not found: 'GMap'.
          new GMap(elem, mapOptions);                                       
              ^^^^                                                          
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:44:8: Error: Getter not found: 'platformViewRegistry'.
        ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(htmlId, (int viewId) {  
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                             
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:37:20: Error: The method 'LatLng' isn't defined for the class '_DispensaryMap'.
     - '_DispensaryMap' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart' ('lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'LatLng'.
        var myLatLng = LatLng(myLat, myLong);                               
                       ^^^^^^                                               
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:38:27: Error: The method 'LatLng' isn't defined for the class '_DispensaryMap'.
     - '_DispensaryMap' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart' ('lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'LatLng'.
        var defaultLocation = LatLng(40.7128, -74.0060);                    
                              ^^^^^^                                        
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:45:20: Error: The method 'DivElement' isn't defined for the class '_DispensaryMap'.
     - '_DispensaryMap' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart' ('lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'DivElement'.
          final elem = DivElement()                                         
                       ^^^^^^^^^^                                           
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:53:19: Error: The method 'GMap' isn't defined for the class '_DispensaryMap'.
     - '_DispensaryMap' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart' ('lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'GMap'.
          final map = GMap(elem, mapOptions);                               
                      ^^^^                                                  
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:56:13: Error: The method 'InfoWindow' isn't defined for the class '_DispensaryMap'.
     - '_DispensaryMap' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart' ('lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'InfoWindow'.
                InfoWindow(InfoWindowOptions()..content = 'contentString'); 
                ^^^^^^^^^^                                                  
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:56:24: Error: The method 'InfoWindowOptions' isn't defined for the class '_DispensaryMap'.
     - '_DispensaryMap' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart' ('lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'InfoWindowOptions'.
                InfoWindow(InfoWindowOptions()..content = 'contentString'); 
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:58:24: Error: The method 'Marker' isn't defined for the class '_DispensaryMap'.
     - '_DispensaryMap' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart' ('lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Marker'.
            final marker = Marker(MarkerOptions()                           
                           ^^^^^^                                           
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:58:31: Error: The method 'MarkerOptions' isn't defined for the class '_DispensaryMap'.
     - '_DispensaryMap' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart' ('lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MarkerOptions'.
            final marker = Marker(MarkerOptions()                           
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                             
    lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart:61:15: Error: The method 'LatLng' isn't defined for the class '_DispensaryMap'.
     - '_DispensaryMap' is from 'package:BuddiesWebApp/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart' ('lib/DispensaryPages/HomeScreens/Map/Map.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'LatLng'.
                  LatLng(currentDispensaries[i].lat, currentDispensaries[i].lng)
                  ^^^^^^                                                    
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_web-1.0.9/lib/src/web_image_picker.dart:7:16: Error: 'FileUploadInputElement' isn't a type.
        final html.FileUploadInputElement input = html.FileUploadInputElement();
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                   
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_web-1.0.9/lib/src/web_image_picker.dart:7:47: Error: Method not found: 'FileUploadInputElement'.
        final html.FileUploadInputElement input = html.FileUploadInputElement();
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_web-1.0.9/lib/src/web_image_picker.dart:12:20: Error: Method not found: 'FileReader'.
        final reader = html.FileReader();                                   
                       ^^^^^^^^^^                                           
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_web-1.0.9/lib/src/web_image_picker.dart:28:16: Error: 'FileUploadInputElement' isn't a type.
        final html.FileUploadInputElement input = html.FileUploadInputElement();
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                   
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_web-1.0.9/lib/src/web_image_picker.dart:28:47: Error: Method not found: 'FileUploadInputElement'.
        final html.FileUploadInputElement input = html.FileUploadInputElement();
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_web-1.0.9/lib/src/web_image_picker.dart:33:20: Error: Method not found: 'FileReader'.
        final reader = html.FileReader();                                   
                       ^^^^^^^^^^                                           
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:45:14: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
        getPath: allowInterop(strategy.getPath),                            
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                               
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:46:15: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
        getState: allowInterop(strategy.getState),                          
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                              
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:47:26: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
        addPopStateListener: allowInterop(strategy.addPopStateListener),    
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                   
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:48:25: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
        prepareExternalUrl: allowInterop(strategy.prepareExternalUrl),      
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                    
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:49:16: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
        pushState: allowInterop(strategy.pushState),                        
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                             
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:50:19: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
        replaceState: allowInterop(strategy.replaceState),                  
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                          
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:51:9: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
        go: allowInterop(strategy.go),                                      
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                    
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:76:53: Error: 'EventListener' isn't a type.
      external ui.VoidCallback addPopStateListener(html.EventListener fn);  
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:34:44: Error: 'EventListener' isn't a type.
      ui.VoidCallback addPopStateListener(html.EventListener fn);           
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:97:44: Error: 'EventListener' isn't a type.
      ui.VoidCallback addPopStateListener(html.EventListener fn) {          
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:217:33: Error: 'EventListener' isn't a type.
      void addPopStateListener(html.EventListener fn);                      
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:223:36: Error: 'EventListener' isn't a type.
      void removePopStateListener(html.EventListener fn);                   
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:287:39: Error: Getter not found: 'window'.
      html.Location get _location => html.window.location;                  
                                          ^^^^^^                            
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:288:37: Error: Getter not found: 'window'.
      html.History get _history => html.window.history;                     
                                        ^^^^^^                              
    ../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:291:33: Error: 'EventListener' isn't a type.
      void addPopStateListener(html.EventListener fn) {                     
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           
            ^^^^^^^^                                                        
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_browser_loader-0.0.6+1/lib/src/style.dart:39:15: Error: Method not found: 'LinkElement'.
        element = LinkElement()                                             
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^                                               
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_browser_loader-0.0.6+1/lib/src/style.dart:46:5: Error: Getter not found: 'document'.
        document.head.append(element);                                      
        ^^^^^^^^                                                            
    ../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_browser_loader-0.0.6+1/lib/src/utils.dart:4:5: Error: 'Element' isn't a type.
    Map<Element, Future> _mapper = {};                                      
        ^^^^^^^                                                             
    Unhandled exception:                                                    
    FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
    #0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:32:7)
    #1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:599:37)             
    #2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:738:21)          
    <asynchronous suspension>                                               
    #3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:554:9)
    <asynchronous suspension>                                               
    #4      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:180:12)    
    <asynchronous suspension>                                               
    #5      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:13:24)
    <asynchronous suspension>                                               
                                                                            
                                                                            
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code            
    note: Using new build system                                            
    note: Building targets in parallel                                      
    note: Planning build                                                    
    note: Constructing build description                                    
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

I ran Flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter package get and re-installed but, I still can get it to run.I'm not sure which package I need to update. Thanks in advance.

DEBUG DUMP:

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
> note: Using new build system
> note: Building targets in parallel
> note: Planning build
> note: Constructing build description
> warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set
> to 10.6, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.9
> to 11.1.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
> ** BUILD FAILED **

Comment: try `flutter pub get` or `flutter packages get`

Comment: That did not work

Comment: @ATrueNovice I`m stuck in the same error. What is the solution to this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try as follow:

Delete `dart:html` in your flutter project if exists.
Do `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` and try running project.

If still not solved,

- Open Android Studio's SDK Manager.
- Go to the Android SDK tab.
- Under SDK Tools, uncheck Hide Obsolete Packages.
- Install Android SDK Tools (Obsolete).

If you have upgrade AS recently that will fix the issue.

If still not solved

Change flutter `channel` to `stable` by

- `flutter channel stable`
- `flutter upgrade`
- `flutter run --debug`

`--debug` args to get more detail when running flutter app.

This [bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17831#issuecomment-395925533) has been fixed from flutter side, please check with android_sdk on your computer if still not solved (let me know `--debug` errors if the problem remains).

Comment: It still hasnt been resolved. After I removed the html and changing to stable. I am using a Flutter Web app

Comment: @ATrueNovice Ops, then you should be in **dev branch** not stable because flutter web is not yet stable.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by removing:

```
import 'dart:html';
```

Since I am not using website, but it was included in the base of create flutter project on the top of the main.dart file.

Make sure to follow the steps of @Blasanka after removing this line:

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`

The problem is definitely that in future when you need to convert to website, you have only extended your problem to different date. Unless you will not make web version.